# about bootstrap glyphicon glyphicon-th-list have a white background

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How do I remove the white background? I have set `background-color:transparent` but still have the white background on it.

Here is a picture:

[image]

My HTML code:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list list-btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu-content"></span>
```

This is my CSS:

```
.glyphicon-th-list {
 font-size: 170%;
 background-color: transparent;
 color:red;
 }
```

**UPDATED**

Thanks for everyone who commented and replied. I have fixed it by myself. I went back and read the whole code that I wrote and found out that the `list-btn:before` made the issue.

```
.left-header-container  .list-btn:before{
    background: white; <<---delete problem slove
    left: 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more code - as little as possible to recreate the issue. It's likely something else in your code causing this.

Comment: Try it: .list-btn{background-color: transparent;}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try adding an !important to the end of your background color? Something is applying the background. Inspect the element on your page and find out where the background is coming from. Possibly from your list-btn style? Can you provide that?